# Import MaterialModule into Feature Module

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I'm trying using material design in my angular app. I imported `BrowserAnimationsModule` and `MdSidenavModule` into lazy loading feature module.

And I got an error in my console:

> BrowserModule has already been loaded. If you need access to common
>   directives such as NgIf and NgFor from a lazy loaded module, import
>   CommonModule instead.

This is my feature module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
import { ProtectedRoutingModule } from './protected-routing.module';
import { ProtectedComponent } from './protected.component';
import { TinymceComponent } from '../features/tinymce/tinymce.component';

// animations
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
// material designs components
import { MdSidenavModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    ProtectedRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MdSidenavModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    ProtectedComponent,
    TinymceComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    SharedModule
  ],
  providers: []
})
export class ProtectedModule { }
```

> What's wrong with my code? can anyone explain to me?

**EDIT**

But, when I import `MdSidenavModule` into `AppModule` and in `app.component.html` add the code below:

```
<md-sidenav-container class="container">
  <md-sidenav mode="side" opened="true" #sidenav class="sidenav">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a routerLink = "/" routerLinkActive = "active">Home</a></li>
        <li><a routerLink = "/dashboard" routerLinkActive = "active">Dashboard</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </md-sidenav>

  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</md-sidenav-container>
```

It works fine!

**EDIT**

I found that `mdSideNav` work in root module only it's wouldn't work in sub modules.

> MdSidenav has been split into MdSidenav and MdDrawer. The MdSidenav is now meant to be used for top-level application navigation, while the drawer is meant to be used for more local split views. While there are no differences introduced between the two in this release, future releases will see different features added to each

https://changelogs.md/github/angular/material2/

Comment: probably you already importing the `BrowserAnimationsModule` in your `app.module` or something try to take it out from `ProtectedModule`

Comment: @Kuncevic: Hello dear friend, When I removing `BrowserAnimationsModule` from `ProtectedModule` and import it into `AppModule` I got nothing, but: `<ng-component>` tag in my `<app-root>` tag, which contains `<md-sidenav>`...

Comment: @Kuncevic: and there is no errors

Comment: so you are trying to use materail module in a featured module that is a lazy loaded module right ?

Comment: @RahulSingh: Yes

Comment: why are you exporting the module back , you want it to be separate from app module add mat design to both the modules that should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I SOLVED IT, Problem was in angular version `4.3.6`, after updating into angular `4.4.4` everything worked as expected...

Answer (score 4):

What you need to do is to implement `CustomMaterialModule` first, that might be looking like:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {
  MatSidenavModule,
  MATERIAL_COMPATIBILITY_MODE,
  MatIconRegistry

} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatSidenavModule
  ]
})
export class CustomMaterialModule {
  static forRoot() {
    return {
      ngModule: CustomMaterialModule,
      providers: [
        MatIconRegistry,
        { provide: MATERIAL_COMPATIBILITY_MODE, useValue: true },
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

Then import that in to your `app.module` like `CustomMaterialModule.forRoot()` and in your feature module import that like `CustomMaterialModule`

In the latest [material 2.0.0-beta.11](https://github.com/angular/material2/releases/tag/2.0.0-beta.11) `md-`prefix gets deprecated
in favor to `mat-` so I would recommend to migrate to that.

> For beta.11, we've made the decision to deprecate the "md" prefix
>   completely and use "mat" moving forward. This affects all class names,
>   properties, inputs, outputs, and selectors (CSS classes were changed
>   back in February). The "md" prefixes will be removed in the next beta
>   release.

Talking about `BrowserAnimationsModule` you better off create a `core.module` and stick that in to it https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-04-11

Comment: It's don't help, it's work only in `AppModule`, but in `ProtectedModule` doesn't...

Comment: can you reproduce online or push your code on github?